# Сохранение кол-ва полей ввода и сохранение данных из них

Tags: c#, textbox

Доброго времени суток. Есть код, который при нажатии на кнопку добавляет новые textbox. После закрытия программы данные поля соответственно исчезают. Как сохранить данные поля для последующего использования?

Comment: Приветствую! Используя файл на диске или БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные от манипуляций, можно хранить в базе данных или использовать .ini файл для инициализации вашего приложения (записывать изменения в него, но это не очень хорошая практика). В целом для хранения состояния приложения используют БД. Возможно, Вам следует пересмотреть архитектуру приложения. Храните кол-во textbox'ов в какой-нибудь переменной и обновляйте ее в БД, при запуске приложения получайте эту переменную из бд и циклом выводите textbox'ы.